# cannot access because it is used from another process

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Well suddenly when I’m trying to run my project from the debugger in Visual Studio 2010 It gives me this error:

```
Error   40  Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\AssetsManagement.exe" to "bin\Debug\AssetsManagement.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\AssetsManagement.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

Please is there someone how knows why that happens?
I have already delete the x86\Debug subfolder and te bin\Debug subfolder but nothing happen
Especially in the second folder the only file which cannot deleted was the the .exe file Also with the same error.

Comment: Is the executable running? Check your task manager, processes list.

Comment: Is this just one time or frequent? Try restarting you VS. Also, when you run without debugging, and then try running with debugging, this error message shows up.

Comment: @Blorgbeard. No my executable is not runing

Comment: @decycline. This happen Only when I run the code from from the debugger. Than will not happen if i run the code for the first time but it hppens at the second and after. It obvious that my VS2010 holds the exe but where and why now suddenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time when I see this error I go look in task manager and I see a VSHost file for my project running.  You can't kill it, it just comes back.  It's gotten to the point now I  always uncheck enable visual studio hosting on the debug tab when I start a new project.

Comment: @dwidel. I cant find any "enable visual studio hosting" in my tools -> Debug.

Comment: Right click on your project in solution explorer and select properties or open, Go to the debug tab on the left side.

Comment: @dwidel. Yes I see it now, I was looking in another place. But I have to tell you that the all condition in my VS2010 returns to normal when I close it and reopen it!!!!

Comment: Closing VS will kill the vshost process and fix the problem for a while.  The vshost process is supposed to speed up the starting the debugger.  In practice I haven't noticed any speedup when it's on and periodically it will keep the project from building.

Comment: If you don't see what is locking it in task manager, try unlocker assistant on that file to see what is locking it.

Comment: @dwidel. I did download an unlocker assistant but its not worked in the debuger, neither in any other action (delete ..)

Comment: @dwidel. Finally when I'm closing the MAIN form i use the From_Closed sub in order to dispose the form and the programm. I don't know if its good but it works.

Comment: @dwidel. I found out an instance which happens in my VS2010. When I run again and again my project from the debuger it run OK. but when i make a change in my code then the error it comes. That is something I face it only today after a long days of work. Is there something cross  your mind?

Comment: @dwidel. I was overcome the error only when unload the solution and reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out AssemblyVersion in AssemblyInfo.vb and performing a build.

Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")

This has worked for me.